# How to access Windows form controls in another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form named `"Form1"` , contains Two controls named `"Button1"` and `"rtDisp"` textbox and class named `"Class1"`. From the class named `Class1` I want to access `Form1` control e.g `rtdisp` to display some text say "abc123" when I click `button1`.

My code is as under: when I execute the following code it gives me the following error:
 `'WindowsFormsApplication1.Class1' does not contain a constructor that takes '1' arguments`

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public string setcodes
    {
        get { return rtdisp.Text; }
        set { rtdisp.Text = value; }
    }
    private Class1 abc;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        abc = new Class1(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        rtdisp.Text = setcodes;
    }
  }
}

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public  class Class1
  {
    private Form1 v;
    public string abc(Form1 v)
    {
      this.v = v;
      return  v.setcodes = "abc123"; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Do you understand what is the error message saying? Do you know what a constructor is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, you are initializing Class1 object i.e. 'abc' in Form1's constructors using the parameter 'this', as below:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    abc = new Class1(this);
}
```

So there should be a constructor in the class Class1, which takes argument of type that form which is not present in Class1. Please put below code in Class1:

```
public Class1(Form1 v)
{
    this.v = v;
}
```

and test, it will solve your issue.

I hope this will help you. :)

Comment: you are welcome, you can read more about constructor at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx and http://www.dotnetperls.com/constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It's right. Read the message. You haven't actually made a constructor for the Class1 object. Even if it is empty, you should still make one. If you want to know more about what a constructor is, I'm more than happy to get into it...

```
public class Class1
{
    private Form1 v;
    public Class1()
    {
        //you normally do your initialization in here.
    }
    public string abc(Form1 v)
    {
      this.v = v;
      return  v.setcodes = "abc123"; 
    }
}
```